# What is the difference between native and emulated widgets?

Tags: eclipse, widget, native

I simply wanted to know what is the main difference between the two. To my understanding, native widgets would include all the icons, drop down menus etc. that the operating system already has. However, I am not to sure about what emulated widgets cover.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about Eclipse SWT controls.

Native widgets are ones where the platform SWT is running on (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux GTK, ...) has a control that does exactly what SWT requires. The SWT code will just interface to the native control.

Emulated widgets are ones where there is no exactly equivalent native control. SWT may implement these using other SWT controls or a combination of several native controls.

For example on Mac OS X there is no native Spinner control, SWT uses a combination of two other native controls to implement the Spinner.

Which widgets are native and which emulated will be different on each platform.